# How to show server name + share name in Finder?

Tags: finder, network, big-sur

When using Finder server shares in macOS, I've always found it problematic that the sidebar only shows IP addresses without the server's name + share name - or some custom name (which would be ideal). For example, by default we have something like this:

[image: sidebar]

Is there a way to customize these so that we can have something like the following?: `server_name/path_name`

Comment: How do you connect to these servers? I ask because if you are connecting using just the IP rather than the host name *that* would be the reason why.

Comment: Usually IP, BUT that still doesn't solve the issue of having a `SERVER` +  `SHARE NAME` name does it?